# In how many possible ways can the projects be assigned?

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

I think the question must be solved like this: 
There is 5 different classes, and three projects. The same class must choose the same project, thus:

The project can be assigned in: $3^5 = 243$ different ways.

Is this the right answer - or did I miss something?

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: Thanks. How do I close this topic? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways for each of the five classes to choose a project.  Thus, by the [Multiplication Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) the number of ways the projects may be selected is $3^5$, as you found.